# drawing tools for (lines,polygon and points) in QGIS 2.4.0

Tags: qgis, graphics

I want to draw lines, polygon and points without necessarily creating a shapefile in QGIS. Please help

Comment: For geospatial sketching I would recommend OpenJUMP. You can draw points, lines and polygons on same layer and creating a new layer is fast and simple because you do not need to define the geometry type or store for the layer.